# Blender paint brush painting weird

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, texture-painting

I am trying to paint my object in blender, I am using F TextDraw. But it is drawing doted color as in below image.

[image]

Also while painting it feels like it is making kind of selection and on user press up click it draws this doted color.

I tried the same in new blender file, it was working perfectly then I tried matching Tools tab all settings like Brush, Stroke etc, everything looks same, still brush behaving differently.

UPDATE:
Please check below for my Tools Settings:
[image]

UV Maps:

[image]

Comment: How does your UV map looks like?

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of your toolbar settings?

Comment: Check texture mask for brush (Texture and Texture Mask rollouts on the Toolshelf), check if in the Stroke rollout Jitter wasn't increased to more than 0

Comment: @LukeD, Brenticus: Please check update for required screen shots. thanks

Comment: @MrZak Rollout Jitter wasnt increased to more than 0, but increased to its max limit, still I am facing the same issue. thanx

Comment: Are you able to post your blend file? Everything in the toolbar looks OK, although 1% spacing is excessively smooth. The default 10% should be plenty smooth. It's hard to say if there is an issue with your UV map without seeing the 3D object as well.

Comment: @Brenticus Yes, there is something messy with 3D object, because I am not facing same issue with another objects. However I cannot share 3D object here, thank you for your comments

Comment: What does object itself look like? (Object mode > solid) Could it be that those dots are details from the mesh? Is Cavity Mask option checked in the Tooslhelf > Options tab? Of course debugging something that went wrong is always easier with file, as you can't share it I'm afraid you need to find what's wrong yourself or append / import object into new file

Comment: Looking closely at the UVs it looks like you may have duplicate faces on your object. The reason I think this is because you have a number of identical islands all with the same spotted color in the same area, just with different (and what looks like opposite) patterns.